# Is there a clean way to do conditional visibility of components in Angular like React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, conditional-statements, angular-ng-if

In React, I can do something like this in my JSX:

```
loggedIn ? <Avatar /> : <SignInButton />
```

Now moving over to Angular (for work so I have to use it), obviously the paradigms are different, but is there a clean way to do this? The best I've seen is:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as loggedIn; else signInButtonTemplate">
  <application-avatar></application-avatar>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #signInButtonTemplate>
  <application-sign-in-button></application-sign-in-button>
</ng-template>
```

This method inherently disconnects the conditional logic and commonly even further separates the templates from the actual condition because most of the devs put it at the bottom of the file so the rest of the layout is easier to read. It's not clean and it's so verbose that it's frustrating on a daily basis.

I was hoping I could create a component (or directive not sure) like:

```
<if-else [condition]="loggedIn">
  <avatar #if></avatar>
  <sign-in-button #else></sign-in-button>
</if-else>
```

and have it not actually render the `<if-else>` wrapper element and only one of the two children based on a condition. We could use this everywhere in our code base instead of the bloated `*ngIf` style. The conditional logic and the positive and negative cases are contained in one block. This is much cleaner in my opinion and was curious if something like this was possible with Angular, and if so, what's the best way of going about it?

Comment: Often I found myself using `*ngIf="loggedIn"` and `*ngIf="!loggedIn"` in place of using the else directive. I think it's a bit clearer and straight to the point

Comment: @CristianTraìna That's exactly what I would do but the `| async` piece of that makes it tricky (I think...)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a switch is closer to what you want?

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="loggedIn">
  <application-avatar *ngSwitchCase="true"></application-avatar>
  <application-sign-in-button *ngSwitchCase="false"></application-sign-in-button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I never even considered using a Switch for 'just' true and false. I was hoping it might be a little cleaner than this, but the really solves all of my major problems for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

well, you can create a component like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'if-else',
  template:`
  <ng-content *ngIf="condition" select="[if]"></ng-content>
  <ng-content *ngIf="!condition" select="[else]"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class IfElseComponent {
  @Input() condition

}
```

You use like

```
<if-else [condition]="condition">
  <hello if [name]="name"></hello>
  <by else [name]="name"></by>
</if-else>
```

See a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mczx2q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fif-else.component.ts)

**Update**

If we use as selector `[if-else]`

```
@Component({
  selector: '[if-else]',
  ...
  `
})
```

You can use in any html tag, e.g. `div` or `section` or...

```
  <div if-else [condition]="contition">
    ...
  </div>
```

But you still has a "extra" tag

Comment: While the other answer is more "canonical Angular", this was exactly what I was looking for. The specific Angular techniques like the double <ng-content> and the select attributes. Is there anyway to remove the <if-else> wrapper element so just <hello> or just <by> is rendered in the DOM?

Comment: you can use a selector name enclosed the name by `[` `]` (see the updated answer) but still you need an extra tag.